# How do I approach a seq2seq problem with timed events?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm looking into building a sequence to sequence neural network, where each element of the sequence is a specific event happening in time.

Specifically, the problem revolves around music: there are different notes happening at different time, each have their own length and can be denser at different times. Raw data could look something like this: `(<note.eventTime>, <note.pitch>, <note.sustainLength>)`. The neural network would then convert a sequence of notes (a musical piece or just a part of it) into a simplified sequence (for difficulty purposes) which is easier to play.

I've been reading up on [RNN with LSTM or GRU](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) to convert natural languages but there's always this element of time in my problem that I can't seem to figure out.

Guess the main question is then: *How do I transform the data such that I can feed it to the RNN with LSTM and preserve the time and the pitch data?*

Answer (score 0):

As stated in keras documentation [lstm](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/) layer takes 3D input i.e. [batch, timesteps, feature].

So, you will have to convert your data to following shape before feeding it to LSTM.

```
[[[Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00') 0 11]
  [Timestamp('2022-08-02 00:00:00') 1 12]
  [Timestamp('2022-08-03 00:00:00') 2 13]]

 [[Timestamp('2022-08-04 00:00:00') 3 14]
  [Timestamp('2022-08-05 00:00:00') 4 15]
  [Timestamp('2022-08-06 00:00:00') 5 16]]

 [[Timestamp('2022-08-07 00:00:00') 6 17]
  [Timestamp('2022-08-08 00:00:00') 7 18]
  [Timestamp('2022-08-09 00:00:00') 8 19]]]
```

Here we used `timestep` of 3. The following makes up one sequence:

```
[[Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00') 0 11]
  [Timestamp('2022-08-02 00:00:00') 1 12]
  [Timestamp('2022-08-03 00:00:00') 2 13]]
```